# New added product image not showing in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have added a new product in my web site by csv and it uploaded but product image not showing on front end and back end  also but old product in showing there image .

Please help me ...

Comment: no image cache is creating in media folder

Answer (score 0):

First flush the entire cache using the backend or ssh.  Then in the backend you may need to go to 'manage products'->select a product -> then select the images tab and assign the image to base, small,thumbnail etc.

Comment: hmm.  You might want to use Magmi to import products.

Comment: can you enplane it please

Comment: old product images are showing but newly added product image not